# What does "on the fly" mean in the streaming technology field?

Tags: video-streaming

"on the fly" appears in many articles on streaming technology, and some tutorials about streaming engine like Wowza and Unified Streaming. But I don't understand the word, what does it exactly mean?

Comment: Off-topic question. It usually means doing something *dynamically* as opposed to *statically*, as in transcoding a live stream in real-time. It can also mean doing something concurrently with another task without interrupting it.

Comment: @aergistal Thank you! It makes sense to me now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"On the fly" related to streaming usually refers to processing of live streams and delivery of modified result with low latency (almost in real time).

This can include encoding with different codecs, bitrate (transcoding), packetising streams (for delivery as HLS, MPEG-DASH and similar formats available over HTTP).